# How to push text value into array

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a JavaScript push method to add value into array, in the style of:

```
title = document.getElementById('tit').value;
description = document.getElementById('desc').value;
if (localStorage.getItem('itemJson') == null) {
    itemJsonArray = [];
    itemJsonArray.push([title, description]);
    localStorage.setItem('itemJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Use The Following Code To Add A Text To An Array Using Something Like This:

```
title = "First Element"
itemJsonArray = [];
itemJsonArray.push(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push multiple elements to the javascript array by using the below steps.

```js
const arr = [];

arr.push('title', 'description');
console.log(arr); // ️ ['title', 'description']
```